# Average / Sum From bottom to top of Hierarchy - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy

We have 3 tables in SQL Server

[Here is the Schema of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXm8c.png)

Groups will have a hierarchy and those will be mapped to users in user table. And each user will have transactions in the transaction table.

We would like to get the output as:

```
- Company (810)     
    - New York (810)            
        - Administration (310)
            - USER 1    100 
            - USER 2    200 
            - USER 3     10 
        - Support (500)
            - USER 4    500

    - Michigan          
        - Accounts      
    - San Diego
```

Can anyone suggest the SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: You showed no effort, but I would suggest that you handle this type of output format in your presentation layer.

Comment: The requested format is not clear from your description. Please show the desired output in a table format.

Comment: Curious that your _schema_ has data, but no data types. And that there is a `Group_Id` and `User_Id`, but no `Transaction_Id`. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to build a hierarchy of your groups. Afterwards you can join your users and transactions onto this hierarchy.

Here is an example that uses your table definitions:

```
WITH GroupHierarchy AS (
    SELECT
        GROUP_ID,
        GROUP_NAME,
        PARENT_ID,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200),NULL) AS PARENT_NAME,
        0 AS HierarchyLevel
    FROM GROUPS g
    WHERE g.PARENT_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        g.GROUP_ID,
        g.GROUP_NAME,
        g.PARENT_ID,
        gh.GROUP_NAME AS PARENT_NAME,
        HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
    FROM GROUPS g
        INNER JOIN GroupHierarchy gh ON gh.GROUP_ID = g.PARENT_ID
)
SELECT 
    gh.PARENT_NAME,
    gh.GROUP_NAME,
    HierarchyLevel,
    [USER_NAME],
    SUM([VALUE]) AS TransactionSum,
    AVG([VALUE]) AS TransactionAvg
FROM GroupHierarchy gh
    LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS u ON u.GROUP_ID = gh.GROUP_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TRANSACTIONS t on t.[USER_ID] = u.[USER_ID]
GROUP BY PARENT_NAME, GROUP_NAME, HierarchyLevel, [USER_NAME]
ORDER BY PARENT_NAME, GROUP_NAME, HierarchyLevel, [USER_NAME]
```

The above query will give you an output format like this:

```
PARENT_NAME    GROUP_NAME      HierarchyLevel USER_NAME    TransactionSum TransactionAvg
-------------- --------------  -------------- ------------ -------------- --------------
NULL           Company         0              NULL         NULL           NULL
Company        Michigan        1              User 3       44             22
Company        Michigan        1              User 4       100            100
Company        New York        1              User 1       310            103
Company        New York        1              User 2       570            190
Company        San Diego       1              User 5       54             54
Company        San Diego       1              User 6       NULL           NULL
Michigan       Accounts        2              User 9       NULL           NULL
Michigan       Finance         2              User 10      NULL           NULL
New York       Administration  2              User 7       NULL           NULL
New York       Support         2              User 8       NULL           NULL
San Diego      Sales           2              NULL         NULL           NULL
San Diego      Service         2              NULL         NULL           NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all built in to SQL now.  Go with:

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP(PARENT_NAME, GROUP_NAME, [USER_NAME])
```

The lower level fields will be `NULL` when the values are being rolled-up.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx for more, and for how to deal with `NULL`s in the source fields (if applicable), and beutify the `NULL`s in the output.  (Lots of `ISNULL`s.)